# We use this everyday without noticing, but we hate it when we feel it

Tags: riddle, word

**Here is a word with an uncertain number of letters *(hint: it's not 4 letters)*: ####**

- We use #### everyday.
- We use #### when we write, play video games, exercise, eat, heck, I'm using #### as I'm typing!
- #### is something that we all can give to others, yet it is not good to do so.
- We hate to feel ####, but we all have in our lives.

**What is ####?**

Comment: Is the word the exact same in every scenario? or can it change tenses, etc? E.G. Blah Blahs Blah'd

Comment: @ITAlex Ideally, **it should be the exact same**. Fortunately, **that's just the case for my puzzle**. Which is also why the grammar doesn't work for many of the answers.

Comment: I based that on the fact that yesterday various answers were at -1 with a criticical comment from you. But I'll concede that the downvote is an assumption. Either way my point stands aside from that aspect. You're using my own link as justification that "give" is good grammer, but it doesn't say that anywhere. What it does say is that it is non-idiomatc, and if you're going to use non-idiomatic grammer then you should be more reasonable with other answers where the grammer isn't perfect. With such criticisms, we had a reasonable expectation that the "correct" answer would be a perfect fit.

Comment: Otherwise, it's not a reasonable puzzle. I for one spent time trying to find an answer which fits the grammer of the 4 statements perfectly, because I assumed from your comments that anything other than that would be rejected.

Comment: @JBentley To give someone pressure is perfect grammar.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is the answer pressure? It seems to fit all the descriptions.

We use #### everyday.

> We need to use pressure to get out from bed....

We use #### when we write, play video games, exercise, eat, heck, I'm using #### as I'm typing!

> In writing we apply the pressure of the pen on the paper, when we play computer games we apply pressure on the buttons. Excercise requires pressure to run, lift weights etc...,  with eating our teeth applies pressure to the food to break it down, in typing we apply pressure on the keys to type.

#### is something that we all can give to others, yet it is not good to do so.

> We can give others pressure to make them do what we want them to do but it usually can upset them.

We hate to feel ####, but we all have in our lives.

> Pressure, in the mental sense is unpleasant, and we all encounter it in our lives.

Comment: Isn't the grammar "I hate to feel pressured" rather than I hate to feel pressure? Hmm, I guess it could work? "I hate to feel pressure" is syntactically odd, though I guess not incorrect by any means.

Comment: @PrinceNorthLæraðr From [italki](https://www.italki.com/post/question-453103?hl=en): *'feel pressured' is when you feel pressured by someone, whereas 'feel pressure' is more general - it might be something you impose on yourself.*

Answer (score 6):

The answer is

> STRESS

We use it everyday

> Positive stress or negative stress we use it

Any activities like exercise or typing puzzles will create some of it

> we give stress to others but not good to do so

We hate to feel

> stressed

Answer (score 4):

I get the feeling that this riddle might be a bit vague a lot of the answers here already make enough sense to me to be correct, but here is another guess:

> Control

We use #### everyday.

> We often control and manipulate the things around us using all sorts of tools.

We use #### when we write, play video games, exercise, eat, heck, I'm using #### as I'm typing!

> We control what we write and what we write with, we control video games, we control our exercise, we control what we eat, we control what we type and even have a control key!

#### is something that we all can give to others, yet it is not good to do so.

> We can give up control to others, but who wants to give up autonomy?

We hate to feel ####, but we all have in our lives.

> Not many people want to feel too controlled. Most people desire freedom from control.

I hope you don't have an issue with the grammar.

Comment: Can you explain the downvote?

Comment: I believe it's because feeling rot13(pbageby) is good, that it's feeling rot13(pbagebyrq) that is bad, though I can't be sure.

Answer (score 3):

Is it:

> Nerves?

We use #### everyday.

> Any human that you'd call living is using their physical nerves in some way.

We use #### when we write, play video games, exercise, eat, heck, I'm using #### as I'm typing!

> You use nerves to think, to move, to do all the things listed.

#### is something that we all can give to others, yet it is not good to do so.

> Nerves, in the emotional sense (i.e. stress/anxiety), is something you can give to others. It is generally seen as an unkind thing to do since "emotional" nerves can be seen as suffering to most people.

We hate to feel ####, but we all have in our lives.

> Feelings of anxiety, stress, or worry are all very common. Most human beings will feel some variety of 'nerves' and most will not like it.

Definition:

> Nerve (noun pl. nerves)
>         1.
>     a whitish fibre or bundle of fibres in the body that transmits impulses of sensation to the brain or spinal cord, and impulses from these to the muscles and organs.
>     2.
>     one's steadiness and courage in a demanding situation.
>     "an amazing journey which tested her nerves to the full"
>     3.
>     feelings of nervousness.
>     "his first-night nerves soon disappeared"
>     Similar: anxiety, tension, worry
>
>     (specifically definitions 1 and 3)

Comment: The grammar doesn't fit.

Comment: @entioneveryone I disagree. It might not be the answer you are looking for. But it does grammatically fit due to the multiple definitions of the word.

Comment: rot13(Areirf) is plural; "cats is" should be "cats are".

Comment: But is singular as an emotion. e.g. happiness is, sadness is

Comment: Yes, but with the word you gave, the grammar does not fit there. *(Sorry, I mad a typo in the first comment.)*

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the answer is

> Heart

We use #### everyday

> It keeps us alive

We use #### when we write, play video games, exercise, eat, heck, I'm using #### as I'm typing!

> You need blood pumping around your body to do any of these activities so you would be using your heart when you do this

#### is something that we all can give to others, yet it is not good to do so.

> Literally, it would be a bad idea but you can also give your heart figuratively, which doesn't always work out.

We hate to feel ####, but we all have in our lives.

> Heart palpitations can usually be a sign of a more significant medical issue.

Comment: *We hate to feel ####, but we all have in our lives.* I'm not sure we all have had rot13(urneg cnycvgngvbaf)...

Comment: The idea here is meant to be that rot13(srryvat lbhe urneg hfhnyyl zrnaf cnycvgngvbaf. Abeznyyl, jr pnaabg srry bhe urneg, bayl va guvf pvephzfgnapr, fb gur fragrapr vf "Jr ungr gb srry **gur urneg**, ohg jr nyy unir va bhe yvirf.")

Comment: *Abeznyyl, jr pnaabg srry bhe urneg,* so *but we all have in our lives* doesn't apply.

Comment: @entioneveryone I don't understand your last point, there are a lot of things we have but don't feel (internal organs, for example).

Comment: My point is, the riddle states that we have *all* felt it before. It's very rare for a person to have ever felt a rot13(urneg) before.

Answer (score 1):

Is the answer:

> It ?

> We use #### everyday.

> Well of course we use it everyday

> We use #### when we write, play video games, exercise, eat, heck, I'm using #### as I'm typing!
> ! It is written at the begining of the riddle

> #### is something that we all can give to others, yet it is not good to do so.

> I guess giving it to others is not a good thing

> We hate to feel ####, but we all have in our lives.

> Here I am having some troubles, but I guess we hate to feel it, but we have it in our lives ?

Comment: I guess if this is valid, then it can be applied to numerouse puzzles :)

Comment: Dang, thought I was smart :/

Comment: I supposed some users will find it smart :)

Comment: Hi Meuoua and welcome to Puzzling :) I have a feeling this will end up deleted since it's more of a 'joke' answer than a serious attempt at answering the question with full justifications... Do take the [Tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) and see what else our site has to offer :)

Comment: No problem if this is deleted ! Thanks for the link to the tour, I will have a look !

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit "tongue and cheek", but it seems to fit. Maybe not for everyone, but for some it does.

> Breath mints

We use #### everyday.

> Some people use breath mints everyday, due to halitosis or just because they like the flavor.

We use #### when we write, play video games, exercise, eat, heck, I'm using #### as I'm typing!

> Like above, some people like the flavor and will eat breath mints for any reason at all.

#### is something that we all can give to others, yet it is not good to do so.

> Giving someone breath mints is often a signal to the recipient that their breath doesn't smell the greatest. As an aside, it's usually good manners to always accept a breath mint. Too bad the grammar is a bit off for this to really work.

We hate to feel ####, but we all have in our lives.

> Some breathe mints have an odd texture. Some are super slick and others have a rough texture. Not everyone likes these textures, especially in the mouth. I've had at least one mint that dissolved into a gelatinous mass that wasn't pleasant.

Also,

> the pun from the first sentence was intended.

Answer (score 0):

- We use "####" everyday.
- We use "####" when we write, play video games, exercise, eat, heck, I'm using #### as I'm typing!

> "Smell" can be used in the meaning of one of our senses - we use it every day all the time.

- "####" is something that we all can give to others, yet it is not good to do so.
- We hate to feel "####", but we all have in our lives.

> "Smell" can also be used in the meaning of an unpleasant odour our sense of smell recognizes. It's not good to  give off smell in presence of other people and we hate to feel the smell.

Comment: This is really stretching some off the lines, because the tenses/parts of speech aren't matching up.

Comment: @bobble perhaps. I'm not a native speaker.

Answer (score -1):

> (an) Eye?

> We use `####` everyday.

> *To see, of course. Well, some of us don't.*

> We use `####` when we write, play video games, exercise, eat, heck, I'm using `####` as I'm typing!

> *Probably no explanation needed*

> `####` is something that we all can give to others, yet it is not good to do so.

> *Transplantation is possible, but is generally avoided unless really necessary.*

> We hate to feel `####`, but we all have in our lives.

> *Touching an eye is mostly universally considered yucky, but almost everyone has had to do it at least once, usually to remove irritating debris*

Comment: The grammar doesn't fit.

Answer (score -1):

I would have proposed

> time

Except that it does have 4 letters.  And giving time is good.  So, well...

Another possibility:

> a finger

Comment: I did wonder about rot13(svatre) I like the humour in giving it to someone but not everyone has them and they're not always bad to give someone.

Comment: Giving someone rot13(gvzr) is considered polite/patient.

Answer (score -2):

(Thanks to @Joshua in comments)

> We use **intestine** everyday.
>  We use **intestine** when we write, play video games, exercise, eat, heck, I'm using **intestine** as I'm typing!
>  **Intestine** is something that we all can give to others, yet it is not good to do so.
>  We hate to feel **intestine**, but we all have in our lives.

Explanation:

> Your intestines work in the background, processing the food you ate, even when you're not eating.
>  You can rip out your intestines and throw them at people. Strongly not recommended.
>  They're all slimy and stuff, but you've felt sick before.